# Total Network Traffic of a specific PORT or USER

Tags: networking, ssh

I want to provide a 'SSH Tunnel' for one of my customers, and I need to know the total network traffic by its PORT or USER.

for example: I will give him/her an access to my server by an exclusive username like TEST and port 7070, and after a week I need to know the total traffic of PORT 7070 | USER Test in MB or GB.

so Live|Real Monitoring is not an option in my case.

P.S. under Ubuntu 22.04 or any other distros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `iptables` rules to mark all packets that you are interested in, and then use `iptables -L -v` to check how many packets and bytes matched those rules.

In your specific example, for counting packets of a specific user, you can try this:

```
# Add a mark in all outgoing packets
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <user_id> -j MARK --set-mark 1
# Save the mark in conntrack, so you can track return packets
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
# Restore the mark in incoming packets
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
# Use some rule (e.g. ACCEPT) to accept incoming packets that have your mark.
# This rule is just needed for your counting, so you may want to use something
# different than ACCEPT here.
iptables -t mangle -I INPUT -m mark --mark 1 -j ACCEPT
```

With this, you can count packets from user `<user_id>` like this:

```
iptables -L -v -n -t mangle
```

and check the entries of the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` rules created above
(use `-vv` to get more details and exact numbers instead of MB/GB/etc)

Now, this will only count packets initiated by the user for outgoing connections, probably will miss the actual ssh packets. For those you can add two extra rules (but please double check to make sure you are not double counting these):

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -t tcp -m tcp --dport 7070 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -t tcp -m tcp --sport 7070 -j ACCEPT
```

Please note that I used `-I` in all rules to make sure they come before any other rules you may have, but make sure you add them instead in the correct place of your firewall, where you want to have them.

**Update**

Something to keep in mind: the counters would not survive a reboot, or flushing and recreating the iptables, so you should also think of having a cronjob or something similar to scrape these numbers in periodic intervals and save them in some database or log files.

Also: **Some alternative method:**

Depending on what exactly you are doing, if you just need to provide a tunnel but don't need to give access to the actual machine:

You can run an ssh server in a docker container and expose the ssh listening port to the port you want to expose (e.g. 7070 as in your example). Then, you can simply run `ifconfig` in the container which will give you the number of packets and bytes that have gone through its interface. This has the additional benefit of better isolation of the customer.